# Impossible to install composer-cli then nvm keeps showing the same error

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was trying to follow that tutorial recommended by IBM to use hyperledger : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html#macos

and then

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

But there began my hell.

I got as far as:

```
npm install -g composer-cli
```

in the terminal to install composer-cli which seems to be essential to develop with hyperledger. However all I got what a MASSIVE error block, which were mainly those 3:

```
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR

gyp ERR! build error 

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

The last one being plainly false since I installed the whole xcode package and activated command line tools. On the advice of strangers arguing on the github forum, i reinstalled nvm and aimed for some specific version. But all I got was that:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos
Referenced from: /anaconda3/bin/../lib/libcurl.4.dylib
Expected in: /anaconda3/bin/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

I tried to solve it in multiple ways, reinstalling and updating everything that makes nvm and xcode, reinstalling python, node (using homebrew), even replacing a space in my profil name with _ so there won't be a risk but that won't work in any way and I always have the same error message. For everything related to nvm or curl as a matter of fact, except version checking.

I ran a

```
homebrew doctor
```

but that wasn't very helpful.

I didn't change my path on my profile, it is still the default path. I'm running python 3.6.5 since that seemed to be pretty important, after reverting back to 2.7 because npm directly told me it was better (?! i was surprised) along with the errors I got. But that didn't solve anything.

I'm really all out of options and seriously starting to get lost in all the procedures and versions I'm installing. Help ? :) I'm on a 10.13.5 macbook pro 2015

Answer (score 0):

I have had a slight different error to start with, even though this was the same

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

which I managed to solve with the following GitHub comment:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569

I hope this helps.